# Handling environment variables in SSR with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm applying `SSR` to a pre-existing `Angular` project. In the previous Client Side Rendering `CSR` implementation, I used the global variable `window` to handle `ENV VARS` for one build - multiple deployments `CI/CD` purposes following this [article](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/).

I tried using a custom service to pass the `env vars` to `app.modules.ts` using the `APP_INITIALIZER` with no success because the usage of envirement with `forRoot()` will be called way before my service. Also, `webpack` can't help in this situation because of one build - multiple deployments requirment.

As the example bellow I tried to inject the `EnvironmentService` in a module but it seems that data isn't fetched yet from the file as metioned in the article above.

```
import { EnvironmentService } from './environments/EnvironmentService';

let envService: EnvironmentService;

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [ServerLogModule.forRoot(envService.ENV_VARS)],
    providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough, is calling `ServerLogModule.forRoot()` mandatory? I mean is it possible to change the code in the service, or is the service being imported from a third party library?

Can you add the code of you `ServerLogModule`?

Comment: I use to have our own modules using `forRoot` and I solve them there. The problem now is with the many third-party modules such as `ServerLogModule` in the example above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• Passing an environment variable to `forRoot()` method from another service in `app.modules.ts`'s providers won't be possible since you won't be able to retrieve any data before the method is called.

In order for this to work, it's better to use `webpack` to create at build time an `environment.ts` file with the correct data, and use it in `app.modules.ts` [this may help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-file-webpack-plugin)

• The article mentioned in your question -as you said- would work very well for a Client Side Rendering situation, but using the same approach for `SSR` may require lots of changes for some/many architectural choices you may have already made.